# Understanding Python Functions

Tags: python

Currently I have this function:

```
x = 0
limit = 10
y = 7
def basic(x):
    global y
    while x <= limit:
        if x == 0 or 1:
            y += 1
            basic(x+1)
            return x
        else:
            y += 2
            basic(x+1)
            return x

basic(x)
print(y)
```

When I print y it returns 18 which means that it is stuck in the if statement and would not go to the else statement but x does stop at the limit hence y = 18. I looked up various sources online but I cannot get an exact clear visualization of my problem.

Comment: `if x==0 or 1` always returns `True` , you need to change it to `if x==0 or x==1`.

Comment: i.e. you want `if x == 0 or x == 1`, or even `if x in range(1)`

Comment: or mayb `if x < 2`

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm not sure this is the right way to say to some newbie that your code is not great, maybe writing an answer with modified version is better aproach.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I apologize for my code, I'm not trying to implement this anywhere or turn it in as homework or anything like that, I was just learning python in my free time and was writing random code to try to understand how functions work. It would be great if you could show me a function that does the same thing but more efficiently and it would also be a good learning experience for me!

Comment: It would help if you would explain what the function is supposed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is probably

```
if x == 0 or 1:
```

Acutally, that will firstly test if x == 0, and if x != 0 that will test if 1 is True. Since 1 is always True, that branch will always get executed.

You're probably looking to do

```
if x == 0 or x == 1:
```